# How to print comma-separated list with hamlet?

Tags: templates, haskell, yesod, hamlet

With the hamlet templating language that comes with yesod, what is the best way of printing a comma-separated list?

E.g. assume this code which just prints one entry after another, how do I insert commas in between the elements? Or maybe even add an “and” before the last entry:

```
The values in the list are
$ forall entry <- list
    #{entry}
and that is it.
```

Some templating languages such as [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_FOREACH) provide directives to detect the first or last iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built-in like that. Fortunately, it's easy to use helper functions in Hamlet. For example, if your items are plain strings, you can just use `Data.List.intercalate` to add commas between them.

```
The values in the list are 
#{intercalate ", " list} 
and that is it.
```

If you want to do fancier things, you can write functions to work with Hamlet values. For example, here's a function which adds commas and "and" between the Hamlet values in a list.

```
commaify [x] = x
commaify [x, y] = [hamlet|^{x} and ^{y}|]
commaify (x:xs) = [hamlet|^{x}, ^{commaify xs}|]
```

This uses `^{...}` syntax to insert one Hamlet value into another. Now, we can use this to write a comma-separated list of underlined words.

```
The values in the list are 
^{commaify (map underline list)} 
and that is it.
```

Here, `underline` is just a small helper function to produce something more interesting than plain text.

```
underline word = [hamlet|<u>#{word}|]
```

When rendered, this gives the following result.

```
The values in the list are <u>foo</u>, <u>bar</u> and <u>baz</u> and that is it.
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is good collection of solutions, though none as satisfying as what Template Haskell provides. Maybe I ought to submit a patch for a sepecial ```loop``` variable to hamlet.