# Recursive Html generation with Hamlet

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I'd like to generate a comment tree.

```
<ul>
   <li> First comment
      <ul> 
        <li> reply to first comment
        <li> another reply to first comment
      </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

I have a `Tree (Entity Comment)` structure.
I would want to have all the benefice of hamlet (`#{commentContent comment}` will be protected against XSS).

How could I achieve a recursive Html rendering with Hamlet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably cannot do it in plain hamlet, but you can create a helper function commentTree that you can access using `^{commentTree comments}`. This function would return Hamlet and can itself use `[hamlet|<li>^{commentTree subcomment}|]` for the recursion and `[hamlet|<u>#{commentContent comment}|]` for the safe interpolation.

(Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7535527/946226).)

Comment: Thanks. I tried something very similar, but I wasn't sure it worked as I hit some hard to understand type error.